# Ivy configuration for springsource repo

Tags: repository, ivy, springsource

I`m trying to set up ivy to get jars from the springsource repo.
So far I have for my ivy.xml:-

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.core" rev="3.0.1.RELEASE"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="org.springframework.aop" rev="3.0.1.RELEASE" />
    <dependency org="com.adobe.flex" name="com.springsource.flex.messaging.common" rev="3.2.0.3978"/>
    <dependency org="com.adobe.flex" name="com.springsource.flex.messaging" rev="3.2.0.3978" />
</dependencies>
```

and for my ivysettings.xml:-

```
<ivysettings>
<settings defaultresolver="spring.chain" deafultcache="C:/repo" />
<resolvers>
    <chain name="spring.chain">
         <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.release">
            <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
            <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/release/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </url>
        <url name="com.springsource.repository.bundles.external">
            <ivy pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
            <artifact pattern="http://repository.springsource.com/ivy/bundles/external/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" />
        </url>
        <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/>
   </chain>
</resolvers>
```

But I keep getting the errors:-

unknown resolver null
  no resolver found for org.springframework#org.springframework.core: check your configuration
  unknown resolver null
  no resolver found for org.springframework#org.springframework.aop: check your configuration
  unknown resolver null
  no resolver found for com.adobe.flex#com.springsource.flex.messaging.common: check your configura
  unknown resolver null
  no resolver found for com.adobe.flex#com.springsource.flex.messaging: check your configuration

Am I missign somethign with regards to the resolvers?

Comment: I forgot to add I`ve ANT_OPTS for our proxy ANT_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=hush_not_telling -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=hush_not_telling -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080

Answer (score 1):

Its due to a typo defaultresolver="spring.chain" should be defaultResolver="spring.chain"